# resizable box with rough edges using svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am working on a small project where I need to build a a box with rough edges around text.  For this I use an SVG with funky edges - sort of a bit like this one: https://ikedabarry.com/InkTex/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Ink_039_6501.jpg (but as SVG).

What I am trying to achieve is that I add this as background to a DIV and that it always fills nicely to the edges of the containing DIV, on all sides, so that the DIV does NOT look perfectly square on any sides. No matter the size of the box (it resizes with screen-size).

This does not work right now.

What we use at the moment:

```css
background-image: url(above.svg);
background-size: cover;
```

This does not work because only half the edges are rough as the other ones extend outside of the visible area.

We also tried:

```css
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

but that does not work because I end up having the image following its own naturally size.

I am now not sure what is the best possible solution using JS / CSS to make this work.

Here is what I see as options:

OPTION 1:
write some JS that:

a. listens to size changes in DIV

b. adds width and height to SVG

c. sets background image as 100% 100%.

OPTION 2:

a. add image as normal image with DIV

b. set DIV as position relative and IMAGE as position absolute

c. set top / bottom / left / right for image as ZERO.
(it does not work right now because it is an SVG - not sure why).

I feel option 2 is the best, but I am wondering if I am overlooking something ...

Any help appreciated.

UPDATE: here is a runnable example:
https://jsfiddle.net/sunnsideup/er1xd0wg/15/

Comment: we could consider using PNG

Comment: Can you share svg?

Comment: It would help tremendously if you could create a *runnable* example of how your text with SVG would look like so we can tinker with it. Right now it's just guessing.

Comment: Hi @EmielZuurbier, I have now added working example below.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
background-size: 100vw 100vh;
```

I am not sure, if this is solution for your problem, but it can help

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately that is not going to work because the size of the DIV is not the same size as the view-port.

Comment: Maybe you can use option 2, but don't use top/right/bottom/left, but use top/left/width/height. I am not sure, but it can have some wired interactions, when using SVG like this

Comment: I am just guessing, you should share some example, so we know, what is really wrong with it

Comment: without an example I can tell you that this is never going to fly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what we have come up with:

https://jsfiddle.net/sunnsideup/er1xd0wg/15/

1. create different SVGs for portrait / landscape divs so you dont end up with BG images that look straight because they are overstretched.
2. remove height and width from svg, add viewbox like this with actual width and height:

```xml
viewBox="0 0 WIDTH HEIGHT"
```

3. add to svg:

```
preserveAspectRatio="none"
```

4. convert SVG to css background:
   https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/
5. add the following css:

```css
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,.... SVG GOES HERE ...  ");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position: center;
```